# Finding indexes of matching rows in two numpy arrays

Tags: numpy

How can I find the indexes of the rows that match exactly between two numpy arrays. For example:

```
x = np.array(([0,1],
              [1,0],
              [0,0]))
y = np.array(([0,1],
              [1,1],
              [0,0]))
```

This should return:

```
matches = [0,2] # Match at row no 0 and 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
np.flatnonzero((x == y).all(1))
# array([0, 2])
```

or:

```
np.nonzero((x == y).all(1))[0]
```

or:

```
np.where((x == y).all(1))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for every pair of numpy arrays if the length is the same:

```
matches = [i for i in range(len(x)) if x[i].tolist()==y[i].tolist()]
```